# How to select a field in a MySQL database by 2 values in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a MySQL Database for a basic quiz program I'm making. The questions table is as follows:

```
ID  | quiz_ID  |  QuestionNumber  |  Question                              |   
1   | 1        |  1               | What is 5 + 5?                         |
2   | 1        |  2               | What is 12 - 4?                        |
3   | 1        |  3               | Whats the square root of 25?           |
4   | 2        |  1               | What is the centre of an atom called?  |
5   | 2        |  2               | What is the nucleus made up of?        |
```

What I need to happen is if $quiz_ID in my PHP equals 2, and $qn (which is the question number) equals 1, then it should display "What is the centre of an atom called?" And then I should be able to increment $qn and that should display the next question in that quiz. I just need some of the basic PHP code to enable me to do this.

So far, I can get it to find out how many questions are in each quiz (with a query), and then loop through them, but this only works for the very first quiz (quiz_ID = 1) I need it to be able to work with what ever quiz the user selected.

I also have 2 more tables, for quizzes and answers that are linked to this table, and when (if i ever get there) this program is up and running there will be loads more entries than there is in the example above, so I need to find a pretty solid algorithm thats going to work.

Thanks in advance, I am so grateful to you guys on this website - when I'm a bit better at PHP I will contribute and answer questions.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you displaying each question individually or all questions for a given quiz at the same time?

Comment: Where is this `quiz_ID` coming from??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For getting all the questions under the given quiz:

```
$quizID = 2;

$query="SELECT * FROM questionsTbl WHERE quiz_ID = $quizID 
ORDER BY QuestionNumber";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while($question = mysql_fetch_assoc($result){

  ...
  ...

}
```

Answer (score 2):

you need basic SQL for this, not PHP.

To query a row based on several criteria, just add them all into WHERE clause

```
SELECT * FROM questionsTbl WHERE quiz_ID = 1 AND  QuestionNumber = 1
```

Notice `AND` operator. it tells MySQL to find a row which meets BOTH conditions.

And PHP has VERY little to do here. It's just adding several variables into text string - an operation you already familiar with.